# nivo slider effects, in order rather than random firing of selected efects

Tags: nivo-slider

is there a way of getting the nivo slider to use effects in order ie:
slideUp --> then slideDown --> then slide slideUp  ect...

rather then using `effect: "slideUp,slideDown"` which randomly fires either effect.

regards sam

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this for you. (Note, I have not tested it or validated it works, but the theory is sound)

```
<script>
var slideEffects = new Array('fade', 'slide', 'fade');
var currentEffectIndex = 0;
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#slider').nivoSlider({
        effect: slideEffects[0],
        afterChange: function(){
            currentEffectIndex++;
            $(this).effect = slideEffects[currentEffectIndex % slideEffects.length];
        },
    };
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a correct version.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var slideEffects = new Array('fade', 'slide', 'fade');
var currentEffectIndex = 0;
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#slider').nivoSlider({
    effect: slideEffects[0],
    afterChange: function(){
      currentEffectIndex++;
      $(this).effect = slideEffects[currentEffectIndex % slideEffects.length];
    },
  });
});
</script>
```